# Multiple selection in Edit mode

Tags: blender-2.67

how to select two different meshes in the same scene? 
After selected I want to join two vertices on both meshes with J, seems to be simple but I am struggling to find in this forum and in google and can not find help. If I select in the outliner turns Object Mode, if click on TAB goes to Edit Mode but I can not select the second mesh vertice only one mesh can be selected at a time. :(
 What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not edit two different meshes in the same scene, only one can be edited at a time. Try to join the meshes before and them edit together. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry it is basic but I was wondering if there is another way thank you Jade. of course help :)